# MFC - How to draw pixel waves inside a rectangle

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, drawing

I am new to MFC trying to learn from the scratch.

I am trying to create a small dialog based application in VS2012 - MFC.

On the dialog window i have drawn a rectangle (in OnPaint event) like this.

```
CPaintDC dc(this);
CRect background1(10,10,208,92);
dc.Rectangle(10,10,208,92);
```

Then i filled the bacground with some color. Like this.

```
   CBrush brush1;
   brush1.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(2,3,4));
   dc.FillRect(background1,&brush1);
```

Now i wanted to draw waves in form of pixels continuously inside the rectangle.

As of now what i have done is,

```
bool top = false;
    for(i=10,j=92;i<200 && j>10;)
    {
        pDC->SetPixel(i,j,NewColor);
        Sleep(10);

        if(!top)
            j-=1;
        else
            j+=1;
        if(j%4==0)
        {
            i+=1;

        }
        if(j==12)
            top=true;
        if(j==90)
            top = false;

    }
```

I am just drawing the pixels straightaway on the window, but within the dimensions where the rectangle lies. And the waves stop as it reaches the right dimension of the rect. But i feel thats not the right way to do it.

I want to draw the waves inside the rectangle and also continuosly, like when it reacahes the right end it should move left and it should be continuous.

Is there any proper way in MFC to draw something inside a rectangle (technically inside another object)?

Please help me out.

Comment: Nice to see you are carrying on ;-). Regarding your question I want to point out the fact that drawing capabilities of MFC (and the Win32 API on which MFC relies) are rather limited. If you want something more advanced then you are better off looking at libraries like Cairo (www.cairographics.org) that have the stuff you need and can be used 'on top' of Win32 API (i.e. the handles you get from objects like CDC etc)

Comment: Cario?  He can easily use GDI+ to get most of what he needs.

Comment: @Ribinson.. I searched a lot on GDI functions for restricting the drawing on ccertain limits but i didnt find any. Can you please share an example or mention any GDI function that does this job ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ScrollWindow function can be used to scroll the existing graph to the left. Then you draw the new data to the right of the scrolled area. The drawing will be much faster if you use the Polyline function instead of DrawPixel: Polyline draws an array of pixels.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess this is what i might be wanting. But using the scroll window function inside the for loop just flickers that particular rectangle portion. When we scroll that portion the pixels that are already plotted in that area should also be moved left correct?

Comment: Got it. Now its working. I scrolled the window left side by 10 units and reduced my x value by 10. Now it is sequential and continual. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and just added some condition, so that if it reaches right side it should start moving toward left.

```
void CMyDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    CWnd *cWnd = FromHandle(m_hWnd);
    CDC *pDC = cWnd->GetDC();
    bool top = false;
    bool right = false;
    int i,j;
    for(i=10,j=92;i<=200 && j>10;)
    {
        pDC->SetPixel(i,j,RGB(255,255,255));
        Sleep(10);

        if(!top)
            j-=1;
        else
            j+=1;
        if(j%4==0)
        {
            if(!right)
                i++;  // if reaches right side i--;
            else{
                i--;
            }
        }
        if(j==12)
            top=true;
        else if(j==90)
            top = false;
        if(i == 200)// make right = true if reaches right side
            right = true;
        else if(i == 10)// make false it reaches left side
            right = false;
    }
}
```

I am getting output something like this
[image]

> NOTE: this will cause infinite loop, you need to check condition where you have to stop printing pixels.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort on helping. This will work for in a way. But what i actually wanted was something like a heartbeat wave forms or forex  trade readings in waveforms, where the waves will be plotted even after reaching the right end as the left end pixels will be moved even left(moving it further left gets those pixels out of the rect) and so that the entire pixel plotted will have an effect like moving left but the pixels will be written on the right side. but it wont move out of the rect (right side) as the entire thing moved left side).

Comment: Sorry guys i was not able to explain it properly. I am just trying to find a way to keep printing pixels inside the rect right side and infinitely(until some stop event). with current logic we can change the limit on x axis but it will keep printing beyond the rect.(which is not logical). So i want to know if there is something inbuilt in MFC or GDI to draw something inside a rect (strictly) so that whatever drawn beyond the rect dimensions wont be even visible(as we are drawing inside a rect).

Answer (score 0):

You are NOT looping with Sleep(10) in your WM_PAINT handler, are you?

MFC or not, you should separate your data processing from presentation.
It appears you are trying to do an animation; the simplest way to do it is to have an off-screen (memory) DC and drawing your pixels on it. At certain times (frame rate?), you would call parent's InvalidateRect()/UpdateWindow() pair. Then in ON_PAINT, you would BitBlt() your prepared DC onto your preferred location in the dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will follow this model during plotting.